# Parse method throws an exception

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I am trying to use Parse method available in System.Linq.Dynamic library. When I execute the following simple example,

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace DynamicLINQDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
            ParameterExpression y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "y");

            Dictionary<string, ParameterExpression> symbols = new Dictionary<string, ParameterExpression>();

            symbols.Add("x", x);
            symbols.Add("y", y);

            Expression body = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.Parse(null, "(x + y) * 2", symbols);

            LambdaExpression e = Expression.Lambda(body, new ParameterExpression[] { x, y });

            var c = e.Compile();
            var result = c.DynamicInvoke(1, 2);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

it throws the following exception.

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ExpressionParser' threw an exception.

InnerException
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

[image]
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the InnerException?

Comment: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't use anything from System.Data.Entity, but I notice you've got `using` statements for Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. The example code you've posted doesn't actually reproduce the exception you're reporting. Can you post code that does?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior added a screenshot of the code, I am using the same code which I have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are possible using `System.Linq.Dynamic` in a .net core project.

Tyr uninstalling that and instead use `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`.

Here is an example of the core version of [The ParseLambda Methods](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions#the-parselambda-methods)

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
            ParameterExpression y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "y");
            LambdaExpression e = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new ParameterExpression[] { x, y }, null, "(x + y) * 2");

            var c = e.Compile();
            var result = c.DynamicInvoke(1, 2);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Also an example using ExpressionParser

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser;
using System.Linq.Expressions;


namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x");
            ParameterExpression y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "y");

            var symbols = new[] { x, y };

            Expression body = new ExpressionParser(symbols, "(x + y) * 2", symbols, new ParsingConfig()).Parse(typeof(int));

            LambdaExpression e = Expression.Lambda(body, new ParameterExpression[] { x, y });

            var c = e.Compile();
            var result = c.DynamicInvoke(1, 2);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes using System.Linq.Dynamic in .NET Framework project. The Parse method is not available in DynamicExpressionParser

Comment: Your project is .net core!!. I can say that for sure because I can see ```using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;```. I have updated my answer with a full example. Please remove ```System.Linq.Dynamic``` and add ```System.Linq.Dynamic.Core```

Comment: You have provided an example of ParseLambda method, but I need an example of Parse method.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas in both case you get a ```LambdaExpression e``` do you need to use ```Expression body```?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas I added a new example.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).